# Not able to click element using XPath using Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click an element using XPath . Tried EC also but it shows the error as "'str' object is not callable"

My code

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH("//div[@class='arrow-icon-wrap'"))).click()
```

Attached is the snap of the div:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work for clicking an element that is present.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath_goes_here').click()
```

and i want to note that in your example you dont use the correct xpath, selenium needs the full xpath value, inspect element in firefox only has one xpath thats why it isnt named full xpath but instead a plain xpath, while inspect element in chrome has xpath and full xpath. You must always use the full xpath value.

Comment: I have tried this also , but this seems not working  I have used full xpath also .I doubt this is a hidden element but not sure . Could you tell how to find a hidden element

Comment: You can wait untill an element is no longer hidden. That is an inbuilt function for the webdriver wait. Also, if xpath doesn't work then I suggest you use the css selector. In inspect element it is branded as selector. Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Hi , I am using the below code..but getting time out exception 
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='arrow-icon']"))).click()